# Cakephp response (sending files) breaks when model functions are added

Tags: image, cakephp, response

I have baked a File model and controller with default actions. Now I am trying to add an display function which can be used to show images in controlled manner.

I want to protect images so that display function can check does the user have an permissions to view image (image directory is not in a webroot).

I haven't been able to make it work, but when I started from the scratch I managed to find out that really minimal function did work.

Working function looks like this:

```
public function display($id) {
  $this->response->file(ROOT.DS.'img'.DS.'noimage.jpg');
  return $this->response;
}
```

When I add example:

```
$test=$this->File->findById($id);
```

to the starting of the function everything breaks.

```
--> http://www.example.com/files/display/1
The requested file /var/www/example.com/www/img/image.jpg was not found or not readable
Error: The requested address '/files/display/1' was not found on this server.
```

I have tried with debug zero, file can be found and is readable, obviously because the function without findById works.

Any ideas?

cakephp 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

You path is totally wrong.
Did you debug() what `ROOT.DS.'img'.DS.'noimage.jpg'` actually holds?
I bet all the money of the world that you would probably find the solution yourself if you did

The img folder is most likely in webroot

```
WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'noimage.jpg'
```

Note that paths usually end with a DS so no need to add it again.
So if it really is an image folder in ROOT:

```
ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'noimage.jpg'
```

Also note that you can easily check if a path is valid using

```
file_exists()
```

If the file has the correct file permissions this should return true.

EDIT:
`$this->File->...`: File is not a good choice for a model name as it collides with the existing core class in Utility. You need to be a little bit more creative with your model naming scheme.

Comment: It's not in a webroot and file_exists returns true. Function even works, if I dont have that findById line in it.

Comment: So what is the exact filesystem path to the image? I highly doubt that adding a model method would change anything here. the error message is pretty straight forward.

Comment: It's said in the error message. "/var/www/example.com/www/img/image.jpg" cake is installed to "/var/www/example.com/www/app/" directory. I would doubt that also unless it woudn't work without it. Maybe this has something to do with headers, spaces or something. This is really confusing, because this should be quite easy thing to do.

Comment: i agree, it is easy to do. The only other explanation i can think of is wrong file permissions.

Comment: That's also checked, owner is www-data and permissions are 777. And still, without any model functions everything works. On that side everything should be ok. But what does those model functions do for this? even $this->File->recursive=0; breaks it.

Comment: Thanks mark, I have just had this exact problem and it was indeed caused by my model being named "File". Re-naming it to "FileUpload" caused everything to work as it should.